# Householder Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have recently started looking at the Householder QR Factorisation and I came across this algorithm. However I am having trouble understanding it .

[image]

I was hoping someone could explain the second last line on what it does and how it relates to the Householder reflection.

Comment: Do you specifically mean the line $$A_{k:m,k:n} = A_{k:m,k:n} - 2v_k(v_k^*A_{k:m,k:n})?$$

Comment: Yes thats the bit I don't get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $I - 2v_kv_k^*$ is the Householder reflection associated with $v_k$.  We can rewrite that last line as 
$$
A_{k:m,k:n} = (I - 2v_kv_k^*)A_{k:m,k:n}
$$